# How to change alignment of row header column of table rendered using R package rhandsontable?

Tags: javascript, css, r, rhandsontable

In the below minimal code examples (first one without Shiny, second one with Shiny), I'm trying to figure out how to change the alignment of the contents of the row header column in this table rendered using R package rhandsontable. The row header column contents are currently centered, I'm trying to see how you can change the aligment to left and right. I tried adding `%>% hot_col(0, halign='htLeft')` but this only works for non-header columns (it doesn't accept the value I tried of 0 for accessing the row header column).

Any suggestions for how to do this? I assume this takes some CSS or js.

**Code version without Shiny:**

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(
        integer = 1:5,
        numeric = rnorm(5),
        factor_allow = factor(letters[1:5], 
                              levels = letters[5:1],
                              ordered = TRUE
                              ),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rownames(DF) <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")

rhandsontable(DF,rowHeaderWidth = 96) %>%
hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)
```

**Code version with Shiny:**

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)


DF = data.frame(
        integer = 1:5,
        numeric = rnorm(5),
        factor_allow = factor(letters[1:5], 
          levels = letters[5:1],
          ordered = TRUE),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )

rownames(DF) <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")


ui <- fluidPage(br(), rHandsontableOutput('my_table'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$my_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(DF) %>%
    hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**I_O solution for code without Shiny** (see Answers for solution for code with Shiny):

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(htmltools)

DF = data.frame(
        integer = 1:5,
        numeric = rnorm(5),
        factor_allow = factor(letters[1:5], 
                              levels = letters[5:1],
                              ordered = TRUE
                              ),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rownames(DF) <- c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five")

rhandsontable(DF,rowHeaderWidth = 96) %>%
hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)

browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      tags$style("th{text-align:right !important; ## [1]
                          color:red !important}" ## [2]
      ) 
    ),
    my_table ## don't forget to specify widget
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, modifying the CSS is one approach. That should be possible via a [renderer function](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#Custom_Renderer), but you could also include custom CSS.
In your case, you'd probably best target the `th` element (the dedicated class `.colHeader` is applied to a `<span>` within which text aligning doesn't make much sense).

If you're serving the table as part of a Shiny app, [here's how](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). Example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      th{text-align:right !important;
         width: 96px; ## you can specify the width here, too
      "))
  ),
## ...
rHandsontableOutput('my_table')
## ...
)
```

In a larger project, you might prefer to maintain CSS styling in a separate file (see section File-based CSS of [above ressource](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)).

Otherwise, you could try this:

```
library(htmltools)

## ...
my_table <- rhandsontable(DF,rowHeaderWidth = 96) %>%
            hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)
## ...

browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
           tags$style("th{text-align:right !important; ## [1]
                          color:red !important}" ## [2]
            ) 
         ),
    my_table ## don't forget to specify widget
  ))
)
```

[1] note the `!important` to override other definitions
[2] just to verify function at first glance, remove later ...

Comment: Hi I_O, that works nicely! I do need this to work in Shiny and I attempted to pull it in unsuccessfully, see my commented-out code in the revised post showing the Shiny version.  However, if I use your solution with browsable() it works fine but I've never seen this before and I've never rendered a table without using something like  rHandsontableOutput('my_table') in the UI. What's wrong with my CSS attempt? And are there any drawbacks to using browsable() instead of the usual plotOutput, tableOutput, xxxOutput, etc.

Comment: The full rhandsontable I'm running allows the user to make manual inputs and edits, those edits are retained (info sent back and forth to the server, etc.). Thus my doubts if browsable() will work

Comment: With Shiny, you only have to include the `tags$head(...)` in the UI part - see edited answer plz.

Comment: If you have several objects & tables in the code and you only want to format one of the tables this way, how do you specify which table is being modified? In my attempt I tried linking the formatting to my_table via ...HTML( "#my_table { th{...

Comment: You already guessed it. Only the correct CSS selector is slightly different. Example: `#my_table th{color:blue !important}`. More on CSS selectors: https://www.w3schools.in/css3/descendant-combinator-selector

Comment: Yes, time for me to study up via w3 schools, thanks!